# How to add a template in a custom page layout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

i have created a custom page layout, which i have used for my homepage. But when i m trying to add a template in it my template is not showing . Given below is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="Magento_Theme::components/slider/slider-image.phtml"/>
    <referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlClass="page-main-full-width" />
</layout>
```

Template is present in the same folder as mentioned in the block (**components/slider/slider-image.phtml**). But the block itself is not showing. I want to display it after the header.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homepage customization you need to create a "cms_index_index.xml" file into your theme

> Vendor/Theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- add additional js or css here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Your header/footer customization -->

        <!-- Create a separate template for slider instead of using existing one's -->
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="home-page-slideshow"
                   template="Magento_Theme::components/slider/slider-image.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- if you don't need title remove it -->
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

You can use the body class for homepage specific styling (cms-home or cms-index-index)

Comment: What if i m creating a another template for other pages, which are not home pages. then how the layout will be?

Comment: @AkshayNaik there are few steps you need to follow for applying different layouts of cms pages:  
1. Create a new layout file on the same path as mentioned above in your theme and use code same as above.  
2. The file name should be like this
> cms_page_view_selectable_[page-url-key]_[name-of-your-layout].xml e.g cms_page_view_selectable_contact-us_contactuspage.xml  
3. Now edit contact us page (Content -> Pages -> Contact us).  
4. Under design section select your layout "Custom Layout Update"

Answer (score 1):

**Please try the below code in your.xml file**

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">            
    <block class="Package\Modulename\Block\Modulename" name="Modulename-main" template="Package_Modulename::Modulename.phtml"/> 
</referenceContainer>
```